# Is it possible to push data into Microsoft PowerBI from Azure SQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, powerbi

I'm working on creating a dashboard with 2 other colleagues. One of the colleagues has uploaded the data into Azure SQL Database. Essentially, I would like to use C# as a programming language and connect to the server and push the data into Power BI. Can this be achieved?

Comment: would be easier to not involve c# , use the built in connections  in power bi  instead https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/581421-azure-sql-database-with-direct-connect

Comment: The other alternative is to connect an Excel workbook to Azure SQL Database and then upload that Excel workbook to PowerBI.  If you want steps on how to connect Excel (PowerPivot/PowerQuery) to Azure SQL Database, I'd be more than happy to post the steps.

Comment: I'd ideally want to use C# as I'm adding this to a solution that my colleague has developed. I can connect to the database using the built in connections in power bi and perform query, but would prefer to run a code which loads the data directly in powerbi. Trying to visualise this in a way in which a code is written to connect to a database and display data in an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you can use C# to push data into Power BI. See the client app sample at http://dev.powerbi.com

But my suggestion is rather than you pushing data into Power BI, consider letting Power BI query Azure SQL Database live. It's called Direct Connect:
https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/581421-azure-sql-database-with-direct-connect

(Thorarins posted this link above first in fairness.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the rest of the replies that involving C# might complicate your solution. That said, have you tried the rest API for PowerBI? This will allow you to push data in real-time into your reports without the refresh constraints.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn877544?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I do agree that involving C# might be a complicated pathway but have no choice. So far I have only managed to write a code that saves the data in the database into an Excel sheet. I recently started looking into Power BI Rest APIs. Maybe the answer lies within it.